# how to get managed bean property values inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Iam new to JSF,

I want to retrieve bean values inside javascript.

Could you please help me out?

Tried like this:

```
function Call() 

{

  var value= "#{myBean.property}";

  alert(value);

}
```

Comment: In real applications using rich component libraries like PrimeFaces, this kind of things should be at minimum extent. If you depicted your real requirements/exact scenario possibly with suitable examples, if any then, it is possible that you could achieve the same thing without using a single JavaScript function at all hereby you use a rich component library in a way that you should.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<h:outputScript>` tag to call any Javascript code within your JSF page:

```
<h:outputScript>
    function call() {    
        alert("#{myBean.property}");
    }
</h:outputScript>
```

Comment: This is suboptimal. Why put the value into DOM? The Page is preprocessed, so it should be no problem to put the value within the script-part.

Comment: Yes @ThomasJunk it's a good point, well I just thought of an easiest way to do it. But instead there's a better solution using only JS. See my EDIT.

Comment: That would not happen, if the JavaScript function were available in its own separate `.js` file. The thing would only happen, if the JavaScript function were available in an XHTML template file (perhaps by additionally using the `CDATA` tag, if needed).